# Switching views in Windows Phone app with MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

Navigation is one of the key aspects of Windows Phone apps, and there are already many questions on this page and others, especially using MVVM Light. At first I thought about using a `NavigationService` implementation, but then I found [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views).

Essentially, the author instantiates the ViewModels of the current content inside the main ViewModel, and by using a `DataTemplate` in `App.xaml` the view knows which `UserControl` to plug in when the `CurrentViewModel` changes.

This seems interesting to me, but as "roberto bandiera" noted in the comments below the article, I don't quite understand the role of the `ViewModelLocator` here. How can I switch the views/ViewModels using the `ViewModelLocator` instead of instantiating the other ViewModels inside `MainVM`? How is the `ViewModelLocator` used correctly when there are more views? I think binding the `DataContext` of other views/user controls to a property of the `ViewModelLocator` could be the way to do it, but then I don't understand how a corresponding navigation command in the `MainVM` should look without explicitly passing a view type parameter as mentioned below.

In case this isn't a good approach at all, do you have/know of any resources or, even better, simple examples of a successfully used MVVM (Light) approach in a Windows Phone 8.1 app (or Store/Universal for that matter)? The `NavigationService` way didn't appeal to me because of the ViewModels passing `typeof(SomeView)` as parameter to the `NavigateTo` method. Does there exist a generally accepted approach to this by now?

Comment: NavigationService is a pretty common thing on Windows Phone and should be used. ViewModelLocator is usually (among a few other things) used for defining all of the VMs which are used for binding to a page, exposed as public properties. That way you bind each view/page to a specific VM exposed in VMLocator. Very simple - most of the time it's 1 VM <-> 1 V (although it's not a rule). Have you tried implementing something and it doesn't work?

Comment: @igrali I was still thinking about how to do things and fiddle around with them. I think I may have found a way I like by having a `ContentControl` inside my main page, bind the type of the currently used VM to its `Content`, and via a `DataTemplateSelector` the corresponding view is created (getting its `DataContext` from the locator). But there's the dependency on the (type of the) other VM again.

Comment: @igrali So I guess I'm not doing things much different after all. So far I don't use a NavigationService because I don't need to navigate to other pages and switching the `UserControl` inside the `ContentControl` seems to be enough. Nevertheless I wonder if there's a "pure" MVVM way of using a NavigationService. But thanks for the advice, I'll not be as resistant to use one in the future, perhaps I will even need one for this app :)

Comment: @InvisiblePanda did you find how Navigate between page? can you help me?